# Polymer: How to show a DOM element not decleared in the custom/core element definition?

Tags: polymer

```
<core-scaffold>
    <core-header-panel navigation flex>
      <core-toolbar id="navheader" style="height:100px; background-color:#E5E5E5; padding-top:18px;">
        <span><my-logo>
          <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </my-logo></span>
      </core-toolbar>
      <core-menu>
        <core-item name="livemusic" label="Live music"><paper-ripple></paper-ripple></core-item>
      </core-menu>
    </core-header-panel>
    <paper-input label="Your Name" block></paper-input>
 </core-scaffold>
```

I want the **paper-input** to show in the navigation bar. But it doesn't. how do I do it? (I tried to put it within the **core-toolbar** tags)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you have imported paper-input in your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it in your core-toolbar it should work.
Have you tried using other html to test if it really is just the papêr-input, or any html ? If this is only the paper-input, it's probably just an import issue (as peter said). If not, it's probably a css issue.
Anyway, sending us a plunk link would help us.

Comment: I'm not working on the project anymore. but most likely your advices are correct. I'm therefore happy to accept your answer and I will surely have a  look asap;) thanks